# How do I pass mocked objects in a mocked container object

Tags: c#, tdd, moq

My method is expecting a FloFilesList which is a class that stores a list of FloFile objects (a class that describes and performs actions on certain types of files)

The method I'm calling returns 1 FloFile based on the value of FloFile.FileName.

I want to use the interface IFloFile to initialize the mock object rather than set FloFile.FileName to be Virtual just because I'm told that Interfaces are the way to go.

```
 var mockFloFileOne = new Mock<IFloFile>();
        mockFloFileOne.SetupGet(f => f.FileName).Returns("FileName.xml");
```

How can I add the mock FloFile into the mock FloFilesList?
I tried this.

```
var mockFloFileList = new Mock<FloFilesList>();
mockFloFileList.Object.Add(mockFloFileOne.Object);
```

This doesn't work as I get an error "...IFloFile is not assignable to FloFile"

How do I mock FloFilesList ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the type of the `Object` property on `FloFilesList` from `List<FloFile>` to `List<IFloFile>`.